# Specify date format in mask when using an input mask?

Tags: jquery, date-format, maskedinput

I've been using the jquery [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to apply a date mask to text inputs.  This works pretty well, but I want the displayed mask to also show the format.  That is, instead of the mask being

```
__/__/____
```

I want to be able to specify the format by using a mask of, for example,

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

or (which looks the same with the current mask but is fundamentally different)

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

I can't see how to do this with that plugin (it only accepts one character as the mask character as far as I can see).  Is it possible with the current plugin?  Does anyone know of an alternative plugin (ideally using jQuery) which can do this?  I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Think this through a bit better. Suppose you could use `dd/mm/yyyy` and then someone types in `29/02/200` (last digit not yet typed in). What should the plugin do for the final digit? Reject all inputs except 0, 4 and 8 without providing feedback? There are lots of examples on this theme.

Comment: Yes, you could validate the date with the mask plugin too - but can you give me an example of a plugin that does this (and has the other behaviour of the mask plugin, such as automatically advancing over the static parts ('/' in the date format)?  I already validate the input seperately and am happy with that, what I need is an easy way to tell the end user what format the date should be in.  If it can enforce a valid date then great (although I still need to validate that certain dates are before or after others) but that's not a requirment for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is supported by https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput (now archived - used to be at http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) - you just have to specify the full placeholder (see the date demo on that site):

`$('#date').mask('99/99/9999',{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});`

Comment: Why mask it as 99/99/9999 when no month that reaches 99? Same as day.

Comment: @Whisk - Clicking your link gives "Error establishing a database connection"

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement recently, and the only thing I could find that didn't require me to do a lot of work on tweaking the plugin was to use [this modified date masking plugin](http://archive.conductiva.com/en/blog/post/76/Improvement-in-the-Masked-Input-Plugin-for-jQuery). It seems to be doing the job so far.

If you want to test it out, [head to this page](http://archive.conductiva.com/files/demos/maskedin/index.html).

The basic implementation we've used with this modified date masker is as follows:

```
$('#yourInputBoxHere').mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY' });
```

I hope this helps.

Update: A word of warning: this plugin seems to be incompatible with later versions of jQuery. I think it's safe for jQuery 1.4 and lower.

Comment: Looks like just what I was looking for.  Thanks  (Caveat: I have tried it at the pages above but have not had time to implement it myself yet)

Comment: A word of warning, though, this plugin seems to be incompatible with later versions of jQuery. I think it's safe for jQuery 1.4 and lower.

Comment: Can you update the links? The current ones are dead.

Comment: Thanks @VenomFangs. I took a look and was able to successfully access the linked pages as of 7/28/2016.

Comment: Or, `$('#yourInputBoxHere').inputmask({"mask": "99/99/9999", "placeholder": 'MM/DD/YYYY'});`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the input as a default value like this:

```
$('#someId').mask("99/99/9999").val("dd/mm/aaaa");
```

Answer (score 1):

*I had similar requirement and so i was used like below option and it is help me to format with date. You need to load input mask jQuery file as well.*

> $("#yourInputBoxidHere").inputmask("datetime",{ inputFormat:"dd/mm/yyyy",     placeholder: "DD/MM/YYYY"});

This is working for me well. so it will help you as well.

Comment: You are using `.inputmask()` not `.mask()` - is this a different plugin?  Can you edit and add a link to the plugin you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own mask to this plugin using the `$.mask.definitions` and then use it in your code.

Comment: I know I can specify my own mask.  It's not the mask that is the problem it's the placeholder (I already have a mask which works).  What I want is something like $('#foo').mask('99/99/9999', {placeholder: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}).  But that uses the whole placeholder string for every character, which is not what I want.